# Copy Dynamic Range Into the Bottom of a Table

Tags: excel, vba

- I have a dynamic range that I copy.
- I want to add a new row to the BOTTOM of my table DATABASE.
- I want to paste the dynamic range into that bottom row.

I have the following code:

```
Sub From_Output_To_Database()

Dim wsImport As Worksheet, wsDB As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim Database As ListObject
Dim Data As Range


Set wsOutput = Worksheets("Output")
Set wsDB = Worksheets("DATABASE")

Set StartCell = wsOutput.Range("A2")

Set Database = wsDB.ListObjects("DATABASE")

  LastRow = wsOutput.Cells(wsOutput.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = wsOutput.Cells(StartCell.Row, wsOutput.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  Set Output = wsOutput.Range(StartCell, wsOutput.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

Output.Copy

'Here should be the code to paste it into the bottom of the table on a new row.


End Sub
```

I tried to google for a few hours but all the code that I write either pastes it on top of the existing table or doesn't work at all.

I hope someone here could help me out.

Comment: "I want to add a new row"... `ListRows.Add`?

Comment: Yeah adding a new row is not the problem. It is pasting the range into the new row that is giving me headaches.

Comment: Use the `.Range.Cells(1)` of the newly added list row as the `Destination` when `.Copy`ing?

Comment: I added: "Database.ListRows.Add
Database.Range.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues" but then I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a new row to the table using [`ListRows.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrows.add).
- Paste into the first cell of that row.

```
Dim newRow As ListRow
Set newRow = Database.ListRows.Add()

Output.Copy
newRow.Range.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: You used `Database.Range.Cells(1)`... the answer uses a reference to the new list row. `Database.Range.Cells(1)` is the first header cell, not the new row at the bottom. In other words, the key is `Set newRow = `